# RavenDB query with projection with parent and last child entry for certain date range

Tags: dictionary, indexing, ravendb, reduce, ravendb4

Let's say I have Post and a Collection of Comments,

```java
public class Post {
 String title;
 List<Comment> comments;
}
public class Comment {
 Date date;
 String author;
 String comment;
}
```

I would like to be able to know for a certain post title what is the most recent comment in a specific date range. The result show be presented as a projection with the following structure:

```java
public class Result {
 String postTitle;
 Date commentDate
 String commentAuthor;
 String comment;
}
```

I'm struggling to get it work, I tried a few approaches, but could not get it right. I have an Index for this but I'm not quite sure how I can get only the last entry of the child element.
I'm getting all the records in the date range and not only the last record.

This is my index:

```java
public Posts_LastCommentDateRange() {
    map = "docs.Posts.SelectMany(post => post.comments, (post, comment) => new {" +
        "    post.title," +
        "    commentDate = comment.date," +
        "    commentAuthor = comment.author," +
        "    comment.comment" +
        "})";   
}
```

This is my query:

```java
List<Result> res = session.query( Result.class, Posts_LastCommentDateRange.class )          
          .whereEquals( "title", "RavenDB Date Range" )   
          .whereBetween( "commentDate", "2019-01-02T10:27:18.7970000Z", "2019-01-25T15:01:23.8750000Z" )
          .selectFields( Result.class )
          .toList();
```

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you loop on 'res' (the resulting records) to find the one record for which the difference between its date and 'now' is the smallest ?

Comment: @Guy thanks for your reply. It's an option but my target would be to have it as directly as possible without further processing after getting the results

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing one result for every post + comment, you could use the index to only output the posts latest comment with the linq Max method.

```
map = docs.Posts.Select(post =>
                 {
                     var latestComment = post.comments.Max(a => a.date);
                     return new {
                                  title = post.title,
                                  commentDate = latestComment.date,
                                  commentAuthor = latestComment.author,
                                  comment = latestComment.comment
                                 };
                });
```

So your index is basically iterating over your posts and outputting a record that holds only the latest comment. Then your query won't have to check over the comments that are definitely not the latest.